# parsing a property from json response

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, jsonp

I have the below code for retrieving a json response. I need to extract the property 'applicant' and put it to the html text field. However I don't know how to do it. I can see the response in the console but the text field shows [object Object], how can I retrieve it to the text field? Any hints? Thank you.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" 

src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


document.getElementById('sudata').value = budata;

}
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form1" id="form1">
<input type="text" name="sudata" id="sudata" value="" size="100">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The response is here:

```
{"ops:world-patent-data": {
  "@xmlns":   {
    "ops": "http://ops.epo.org",
    "$": "http://www.epo.org/exchange",
    "ccd": "http://www.epo.org/ccd",
    "xlink": "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  },
  "ops:meta":   {
    "@name": "elapsed-time",
    "@value": "31"
  },
  "exchange-documents": {"exchange-document":   {
    "@system": "ops.epo.org",
    "@family-id": "35636806",
    "@country": "EP",
    "@doc-number": "1814517",
    "@kind": "A1",
    "bibliographic-data":     {
      "publication-reference": {"document-id":       [
                {
          "@document-id-type": "docdb",
          "country": {"$": "EP"},
          "doc-number": {"$": "1814517"},
          "kind": {"$": "A1"},
          "date": {"$": "20070808"}
        },
                {
          "@document-id-type": "epodoc",
          "doc-number": {"$": "EP1814517"},
          "date": {"$": "20070808"}
        }
      ]},
      "classifications-ipcr": {"classification-ipcr":       [
                {
          "@sequence": "1",
          "text": {"$": "A61K   9/    08            A I"}
        },
                {
          "@sequence": "2",
          "text": {"$": "A61K  31/    19            A I"}
        },
                {
          "@sequence": "3",
          "text": {"$": "A61K  31/   216            A I"}
        },
                {
          "@sequence": "4",
          "text": {"$": "A61K  47/    00            A I"}
        },
                {
          "@sequence": "5",
          "text": {"$": "C07C  57/    38            A I"}
        },
                {
          "@sequence": "6",
          "text": {"$": "C07C 229/    42            A I"}
        }
      ]},
      "patent-classifications": {"patent-classification":       [
                {
          "@sequence": "1",
          "classification-scheme":           {
            "@office": "EP",
            "@scheme": "EC"
          },
          "classification-symbol": {"$": "A61K9/00M5"}
        },
                {
          "@sequence": "2",
          "classification-scheme":           {
            "@office": "EP",
            "@scheme": "EC"
          },
          "classification-symbol": {"$": "A61K31/19"}
        },
                {
          "@sequence": "3",
          "classification-scheme":           {
            "@office": "EP",
            "@scheme": "EC"
          },
          "classification-symbol": {"$": "A61K31/216"}
        }
      ]},
      "application-reference":       {
        "@doc-id": "16272416",
        "document-id":         [
                    {
            "@document-id-type": "docdb",
            "country": {"$": "EP"},
            "doc-number": {"$": "05808069"},
            "kind": {"$": "A"}
          },
                    {
            "@document-id-type": "epodoc",
            "doc-number": {"$": "EP20050808069"},
            "date": {"$": "20051019"}
          },
                    {
            "@document-id-type": "original",
            "doc-number": {"$": "05808069"}
          }
        ]
      },
      "priority-claims": {"priority-claim":       [
                {
          "@sequence": "1",
          "@kind": "national",
          "document-id":           [
                        {
              "@document-id-type": "epodoc",
              "doc-number": {"$": "WO2005IN00339"},
              "date": {"$": "20051019"}
            },
                        {
              "@document-id-type": "original",
              "doc-number": {"$": "IN2005000339"}
            }
          ]
        },
                {
          "@sequence": "2",
          "@kind": "national",
          "document-id":           [
                        {
              "@document-id-type": "epodoc",
              "doc-number": {"$": "IN2004DE02332"},
              "date": {"$": "20041122"}
            },
                        {
              "@document-id-type": "original",
              "doc-number": {"$": "DE23322004"}
            }
          ]
        }
      ]},
      "parties":       {
        "applicants": {"applicant":         [
                    {
            "@sequence": "1",
            "@data-format": "epodoc",
            "applicant-name": {"name": {"$": "VENUS REMEDIES LTD [IN]"}}
          },
                    {
            "@sequence": "1",
            "@data-format": "original",
            "applicant-name": {"name": {"$": "VENUS REMEDIES LIMITED"}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `budata` variable contains an array.  The `value` property of your element is a string property, so when you assign it an object, the object first gets converted with Object::toString(); which will return `[object Object]`.

If you're trying to display the full contents of the applicant property, try:

```
document.getElementById( 'sudata' ).value = JSON.stringify( budata );
```

If you're only trying to display specific parts of the array, you'll have to specify what your expected output string is.

Comment: var budata = oData;
document.getElementById('sudata').value = JSON.stringify(budata);

Thanks to your help, I now can get the whole into the text field.
But how can I get only the part 'applicant'? Or how can I look for 'applicant' property in the array?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking here.  Could you paste the exact string that you're seeing in the text field, and also provide the exact string that you want?

Comment: I am seeing the whole response (I put it below my code) in the text field and I want to see only the part VENUS REMEDIES LTD (at the bottom of the response).

Comment: Oh, I see the bug now; On the line where you're assigning `budata`, you have an extra set of parenthesis after oData. If you remove those you'll get the 'applicant' array, but that is still more than just the 'VENUS REMEDIES LTD' part you're looking for.  To get just that string you'll need to add `[ 0 ][ 'applicant-name' ][ 'name' ][ '$' ]` to your properties.

Comment: Can you tell me why we should put [ 0 ] before [ 'applicant-name' ]? There is no property as  [ 0 ].

Comment: Ok. I got it, it is the sequence of the property.